# To capture limited number of packet only

Tags: python, tcp, packet, icmp, pyshark

I want to capture the limited number of packet. for example, while I am using the command python python.py -I eth0 -c 10 then I wan to capture only 10 number of packet and exit but I am printing many packets instead of 10. please tell me where am I wrong.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import argparse
import pyshark
import time
import re as regex


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-i', '--interface', metavar=" ", type=str, required = True, help = 'To specify the interface ')
parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', required = False, action = 'store_true', help = 'To print the all layer of packet')
parser.add_argument('-o', '--output', metavar=' ', help = 'To capture and save the pcap in a file')
parser.add_argument('-p', '--protocol', metavar=' ', help= 'To capture packet using ptotocl filter')
parser.add_argument('-u', '--udp', action = 'store_true', help = 'To capture udp packet only')
parser.add_argument('-t', '--tcp', action = 'store_true', help = 'To capture tcp packet only')
parser.add_argument('-c', '--count', metavar=' ',type=int, default=1,  help = 'To capture limited number of packet')

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.count:
   capture = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface=args.interface)
   capture.sniff(packet_count = args.count)

elif args.protocol:
   capture = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface=args.interface, display_filter=args.protocol)


elif args.udp:
   capture = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface=args.interface, bpf_filter='udp')

elif args.tcp:
   capture = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface=args.interface, bpf_filter='tcp')

else:
   capture = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface=args.interface, output_file=args.output)
#   capture.sniff(packet_count = args.count)

packet_list = []

for packet in capture.sniff_continuously():
    if 'IP Layer' in str(packet.layers):
        protocol = regex.search(r'(Protocol:)(.*)',str(packet.ip))
        protocol_type = protocol.group(2).strip().split(' ')[0]
       # proto = protocol_type
    localtime = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time())) 
    proto = protocol_type
    src_addr = packet.ip.src
    dst_addr = packet.ip.dst
    length = packet.length
    print (localtime, '\t' , proto, '\t' ,src_addr, '\t', dst_addr, '\t' , length)
    if args.verbose:
       print(packet.show())
```

output

I am capturing more than 10 packets.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> capture.sniff(packet_count = args.count)
> ```

This will immediately read the given number of packets

> ```
> for packet in capture.sniff_continuously():
> ```

This will read packets without any limit.

So if you want to only read the number of packets don't immediately call `sniff` when parsing the `args.count` argument but instead apply `packet_count = args.count` later to `sniff_continously`:

> ```
> for packet in capture.sniff_continuously(packet_count = args.count):
> ```

Comment: it work to capture limited number of packet but when I used command python pkt.py -I eth0 then only one packet is captured. it should be capturing infinite packet

Comment: @user20828450: of course you should use the argument only if a count is given. But you asked for an explanation of the behavior you see - and I've provided the explanation.

Comment: then can you give me answer how to use both the feature to capture limited as well as infinite packet in the above code

Comment: @user20828450: maybe accept answers to your previously asked question first before expecting more help?